# Can you replace a color like black on texture images?

Tags: three.js

I have a high-resolution jpg to make clouds on the planet. However since it is a jpg (couldn't find a good PNG one) I wanted to see if there's a way to remove the black so it's transparent: Here's the image: http://www.benmarshall.me/projects/playground/072012/assets/imgs/earth-clouds-high.jpg

Comment: JPEG doesn't support an alpha (transparency) channel, so what are you expecting? Perhaps you just want to convert the image to a PNG in Photoshop?

Comment: No, I know JPEG doesn't support transparency. That's why I'm asking if THREE.js has a post filter or something that can edit the image or convert to a png.

Comment: If it's just a single image, again I ask: is there a reason to not just use an offline program (such as Photoshop) to do the conversion?

Comment: if you look at the image, it would take forever to edit it and there would be no why to properly replace of the variants of black with their proper opacity, hence why i looking for an option in THREE.js since other 3D programs use textures like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shader, where you send the texture as a uniform along with UVs as varyings. In the fragment program, put an if clause where black ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) is replaced by your color of choice . For transparency, change the alpha value ( last value in the vec4 )- 0.0 is fully transparent and 1.0 is fully opaque. Hope this helps